# Does this differential equation have a unique solution?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Initial Value Problem

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y+a}$ where $a > 0$ and $y(0) = 0$

Does this have a unique solution ?

If I try to solve it :

$\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{y+a}} = dx$ gives,

$2\sqrt{y+a} = x + c  \ldots (1)$

Now, here using Initial Condition

$2\sqrt{y+a} = x + 2\sqrt{a}$ or, $y+a = (x+ 2\sqrt{a})^2$

But. in $(1)$ if I simplify the equation

$y+a= (\dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{c}{2})^2$

and here via initial condition we get two values  $c = 2\sqrt{a}$ and $c = -2\sqrt{a}$
and thus this has two different solutions.

So, can anyone explain does this Differential Equation has unique solution or multiple solutions ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called "solution"

$$y=(x/2-\sqrt{a})^2-a$$

does not actually satisfy the differential equation $y'=\sqrt{y+a}$. Note that, according to this diff. eq., the derivative $y'$ should always be positive, since the square root of a real number, if it exists, is always positive. However, for the "solution" above,

$$y'(0)=-\sqrt{a}$$

which is *negative*. Thus, the only true solution is

$$\color{green}{y=(x/2+\sqrt{a})^2-a}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Answer based on uniqueness theorem**

As $a \gt 0$, the map $y \mapsto \sqrt{y+a}$ is locally Lipschitz around zero and therefore the IVP has a unique local solution according to [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem?wprov=sfti1).

**Answer based on integration**

See the other answer.